# How to create an APK from Pygame using PGS4A?

Tags: android, python-3.x, pygame, apk

Recently I was trying to package all the files from a pygame program into an Android package (apk) using PGS4A, but it says that I need python 2.7.

How to create an apk from pygame with python 3.5?

Comment: Depending on what libraries you're using, it should be pretty easy to convert python/pygame 3.5 code to 2.7(manually). I'd really like to know if there is an actual solution for this though. :P

Comment: Me too, but seems that no one is responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also building an apk from pygame. But the tool -pgs4a actually is designed for python2 only. No tool has been developed to enable to use python3. So only option is python2. Till now it is not possible to use python3 for this purpose.